# How can i update changes of Sass in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sass

When I added my project folder to Chrome "Workspace" i able to make changes and can save my CSS from Chrome itself. But I can only make changes in CSS file. How can i make this for SCSS files.
I given RED background color to this Container here 
[image: I given RED background color to this Container here]
I changed it's background color to GREEN here 
[image: I changed it's background color to GREEN here]
But when i go to the SCSS file the background color not updated 
[image: But when i go to the SCSS file the background color not updated]

Is there any solution for this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? I've the same...

Comment: No i was really frustrated on this issue. I have spend a ridiculous amount of time on it for searching and requesting help from other developers and nobody has been responding to the messages. I still looking to get help on it. I even asked in the google developer channel of youtube and did'nt get any feedback.

Comment: Finally the best solution that I've found: https://christianheilmann.com/2021/09/16/css-mirror-editing-in-edge-devtools-for-vs-code/

Comment: @bevrard Thanks for your link. I read it. Actually I am able to save CSS at real time with Chrome. But my question is How can we edit SCSS at real time. I'm not focusing CSS but SCSS. In Chrome if we add our project in Workspace, we can able to edit CSS and Chrome will automatically save it to our original file. But this feature is not working with SCSS file.  That is my concern. If i get this solution. It will be an Amazing Feature!!!

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the following simple steps

1. Open your inspect element on chrome and click on gear icon which appears to the top right.
2. Enable the CSS source maps (which is I think its enabled by default. If not just check it. After enable the css source map don't close it.)

- The source maps feature gained a lot of attention when it was first
  introduced and a lot has changed since. It is now available in the
  latest stable versions of Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
- You do not require Chrome Canary, nor do you need to edit
  chrome://flags to use this. You only have to apply the correct
  settings to enable it.
- Source maps require Sass 3.3 or above (Sass 3.4 was released
  recently).
- How to use source map for sass : [Check this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-source-maps-debug-sass-chrome/)

3. Click on Workspace tab on the left panel just below the General tab.
4. Add your source code folder by clicking the Add folder button (close the box.)
5. Go on Sources tab and find your scss file.

Now you can make changes and hit ctrl+s it will automatically change on your style.scss.

Comment: Thanks for your initiation. Can you check the following and let me know.
1. Inpsect any element and add a new style in the SCSS file (In the Style Tab)
2. Then click on the SCSS file and open it. 
3. Check the changes you made in the style tab is reflecting in SCSS file